# DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.IAuthenticationRequest RedirectToProvider() ThreadAbortException

Tags: dotnetopenauth, threadabortexception

With **DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.7.11121** I receive System.Threading.**ThreadAbortException** when invoking  DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.IAuthenticationRequest **RedirectToProvider**() method. My call stack looks like

> "   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.**HttpResponse.End()**\r\n   at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.OutgoingWebResponse.Send(HttpContext context)
>   in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\OutgoingWebResponse.cs:line
>   161\r\n   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.OutgoingWebResponse.Send() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\OutgoingWebResponse.cs:line
>   131\r\n   at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.AuthenticationRequest.**RedirectToProvider**()

What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.  DotNetOpenAuth calls ASP.NET Response.Redirect(), which itself throws the `ThreadAbortException` in order to terminate execution on the current page.  If you're using web forms, this is important because it prevents ASP.NET or the page from writing additional HTML after the DNOA response message, corrupting the message.

If you're in MVC, you can use `RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult()` and return that to avoid the exception.